# Arrow icon in MKMapView

Tags: ios, cocoa, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView in my iOS application, and would like to add the "location arrow" icon on it. I am referring to the arrow you get on the standard Maps application that allows you to go to the user location.

Any idea how I can add it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no standard icon for location services. Use the icon from something like [Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/) and create your own toolbar button.

This is one of those things that should be included by default but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

**MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem** should be the answer to your question. I am sure the following code will be helpful.

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:_mapView];
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:curBar.items];
[items insertObject:buttonItem atIndex:0];
[curBar setItems:items]; //curBar is an UIToolbar
```